# MVC 5 bundled files showing up as pending

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

Environment: Visual Studio 2013, MVC 5, ASP.Net 4.5

Website: It is an intranet site that uses windows authentication and available to the users both off and on VPN.

Problem:

Bundled files are showing as "Pending", due to this reason the styles are not getting applied for some users. These users are off vpn. IE works fine for these users, chrome and FF have an issue and one of the users has latest version of both FF and chrome.

Now, i have tested this on my home machine (off vpn and new OS put on it last week) and i can't replicate the issue. I am attaching 2 images showing my (working) and users (pending) views.

Problem Image -- Status is found
[image]

Working Image
[image]

How can i fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: compilation debug="true" works for these users as individual css/javascript files gets pulled without any issue.

Comment: Are the CSS bundles using any sort of transform, like LESS or something? Perhaps they are failing to process on the server, like a missing dependency from deployment or the likes.

Comment: No. The page just showed up fine for me in chrome and ff on a new machine. For users where chrome and ff are failing, IE works just fine. This behavior is showing up for some users not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, ASP.NET url windows authentication wasn't allowing bundling request. I got this solved via [asp.net forums](http://forums.asp.net/p/1953601/5583259.aspx?Re%20MVC%205%20bundled%20files%20showing%20up%20as%20pending).

```
<location path="BundlingPath">
   <system.web>
           <authorization>
                    <deny users="?" />
               </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got through the same kind of "error" and found out my stylesheet wasn't loaded properly. Once the stylesheet was properly loaded, the resources were not in Pending state anymore.

Comment: I just posted my fix. Thanks